# Is that proper configuration? Trying to get htttp redirected to https

Tags: nginx

I have config like this, but it's still not redirecting from http to https. Should I reorder it or I'm missing something?

```
 server {    
    listen 80;

    server_name www.example.me example.me;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/examplefront.error_log debug; rewrite_log on;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/examplefront.access_log; 


    location / {
      proxy_pass http://exampleme.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Authorization ""; 
      proxy_hide_header Authorization; 
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme; 
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.me/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.me/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    listen 80;
    if ($host = www.example.me) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
    if ($host = example.me) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
}
```

Comment: Remove `listen 80;` from your first `server` block.

Answer (score 0):

So what I did is:
- I removed `listen 80;` line
- added `server_name example.me www.example.me` to the block that has `listen 80;`

Seems that `server_name` is required for nginx to even look at this block and then evaluate `if` statement.